# react test-utils does not render any change after act

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a react component which contains a form and a button click which converts the form into edit mode.  My problem is that after the click the event seems to fire ok and the form changes to edit mode, but there is no change in the test ui when unit testing.  When I actually run the application through the browser the change happens.

This is what my unit test code looks like

```
it.only('should display the edit page when the edit button is clicked', async () => {
    let r: any
    act(() => {
        r = render(
            <MemoryRouter initialEntries={['/tickets/1']}>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path='tickets/:ticketId' element={<TicketDetailPage />}></Route>
                </Routes>
            </MemoryRouter>
        )
    })


    act(() => {
        const button = screen.getByTestId('editTicket')
        userEvent.click(button); // this is where I simulate the click, I also tried  button.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('click', {bubbles: true})); but with the same result.
    })

    console.log(r.baseElement.outerHTML)  // when I look at the html it has not been updated
    expect(r.baseElement.outerHTML).toMatchSnapshot()
})
```

This is the code that fires when the button is clicked

```
const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<Inputs> = data => {
    if (!isEditMode) { // set the edit mode
        setEditMode(true)
    } else { // save the changes
        dispatch<any>(saveTicket({
            id: ticketId!,
            description: data.description,
            owner: data.owner,
            title: data.title
        }));
        setEditMode(false)
    }
}
```

Comment: When the `editTicket` button is clicked. Are there any asynchronous actions that occur? Can we see its implementation in the app code?

Comment: sure, I have added it to the original question

Comment: Its quite likely that by the time you log the DOM, it hasnt had a chance to change yet. I'd recommend trying to add a `findBy` query on something within the subsequent page/something that appears only after button click. `await` this, *then* log the DOM